# i need some help about using sessions in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I am using codeigniter. I used session variable to store a id in a function and get the stored value in another function. I have a controller file which is given below:

```
public function select_service($id)
    {
    $this->load->library('session');
         $this->session->unset_userdata('employee');
         $this->session->set_userdata('employee', ['total'=>$id]);
     // $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['service'] =   $this->add_service_model->get_services();  
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/service_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
```

In the above code I get the id from a form and store in the session variable

```
public function services()
    {
    //here i need to get the session variable employee['total'] 
    $id = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $data_to_store=array('employee_id'=>$id,'service_id'=>$this->input->post("services"));
    $this->add_service_model->save($data_to_store);
    $data['addservice'] =    $this->add_service_model->get_addservices();   
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/newview';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
```

In this function service I need to retrieve the stored value. both functions are in same controller. can some one help me with the code?

Comment: You are also using `$this->session->unset_userdata('employee');` This will remove it from sessions

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: Your question and problem but hard to understand

Comment: dont unset anything. use $this->session->set_userdata("employee_total",$total); and then get it with $total =$this->session->userdata("employee_total");

Comment: in your second function, you say you need to retrieve the stored value, but i dont see how you are attempting to

Comment: $id = $this->session->userdata('employee'); by this code snippent i could get my employee id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Manuall](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/autoloader.html)

1. Auto load the session library. This way the session is always loaded.
2. when setting the id do: `$this->session->set_userdata('employee', $id);`
3. when you want to get that id user `$id =  $this->session->userdata('employee');`

Comment: sorry i could not  get you. i have edited my question. in the first function i get and store the id. i need to retrieve the id in my second function

Comment: or he could load it in the controller class construct

Comment: also possible. I'm actually still confused what he is doing with those 2 functions... strange code.

Comment: i agree, its most likely the lack of explanation

Comment: :) i reached my solution thank you for your support.